# Integration of Dropbox in iPhone application error 400

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, dropbox

I am using the great source code called `GSDropboxDemoApp` which nicely integrate the Dropbox in the application. However, after linked to the app to Dropbox, it gives error in loading folder contents. Below are the codes

I have already edited the **info.plist**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation. Fill in your Dropbox credentials!
#warning NB: you must also update the URL scheme listed under the CFBundleURLTypes key in GSDropboxDemoApp-Info.plist
    NSString *dropboxAppKey = @"sxxxxxxxxxx";
    NSString *dropboxAppSecret = @"cxxxxxxxxx";
    NSString *dropboxRoot = @"kDBRootAppFolder";  // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox

    DBSession* dbSession = [[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:dropboxAppKey
                                                   appSecret:dropboxAppSecret
                                                        root:dropboxRoot];
    [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[GSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GSViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked to Dropbox successfully");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"App not linked to Dropbox!");
        }
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

---

### Error Message

```
 GSDropboxDemoApp[4674:907] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/kDBRootAppFolder - (400) Expected a root of either 'dropbox' or 'sandbox', got 'kDBRootAppFolder'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using a *constant*, like so:

```
NSString *dropboxRoot = kDBRootAppFolder;  // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
```

Constants are used so that you don't need to worry about the actual value itself.

Answer (score 1):

And for those of us (in the future that stumble across this question) getting the same error using ruby motion, it needs to be:

```
dropboxRoot = KDBRootAppFolder # Capital K
```